# Android text size really different on 2 different "normal" screens

Tags: android

I specify the text size like `12sp` and I have to write the text in a box of `100dp`.
In one case (3.2in, 320x480 mdpi) the thing looks good, in the other (Nexus 4) the text is way too big and doesn't fit in the box

Why is that ? I thought that 'sp' were independent of the density.

Comment: Have you checked the devices accessibility settings? The user can increase/decrease the device font size, which affects `sp` measurements.

Comment: Fonts of devices may be different?

Comment: No accessibility settings (default) and the font is by default too

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**dp** or **dip** is density-independent pixel, aka it is scaled automatically to the pixel density of the device's screen.

**sp** is scale-independent pixel - essentially the same as dp, but also factors in the users font-size setting (which can be changed within the system settings).

So it might be that your Nexus4 has a different font-size setting compare to your other test device.

If you do not want to scale with the user's font-size setting, you can simply use **dp** as your font-size value.

Answer (score 0):

SP and DP, if I understand them correctly, are not precise in that they group a range of densities together.  Ie, hdpi covers a range of real pixel densities (thus it is possible to see slight variations in actual size but it should not be dramatically different.

You say that there is no user enabled scaling on the N4, have you verified this by switching the text to DP from SP?